# eliminating repetition inside a word with regex and add a tag at the end

Tags: python, regex

I am pretty new to regex and having a hard time dealing with situations of repetition inside of a word. What I want to do is to match any words that have at least three consecutive repeated letters, such as "whateeever", "cooool", and "haaaapy", keep only one repeated letter and then add an "(elong)" to the end of the word. For example, "whateeever" becomes "whatever (elong)", "cooool" becomes "col (elong)", and "haaaapy" becomes "happy (elong)".

Below is what I have done, but it can only eliminate repetition, like "whateeever" becomes "whatever":

```
def re_sub(pattern, repl):
    return re.sub(pattern, repl, text, flags=FLAGS)
text = re_sub(r"(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}", r"\1\2")
```

Then I slightly changed my code to the following one, but the output becomes "whate (elong) ver".

```
text = re_sub(r"(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}", r"\1\2 (elong)")
```

I wonder if there is a way that can move the "(elong)" to the end? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "haaaapy" becomes "happy (elong)" -- shouldn't it become hapy?

Comment: sorry, its a typo, my bad. "haaaappy" becomes "happy (elong)".

Comment: And what about "whateeeveeeer"?:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search with `(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}(\S*)` and replace with `\1\2\3 (\2long)`

So:

```
text = re.sub(r"(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}(\S*)", r"\1\2\3 (\2long)", the_input_string)
```

The input:

> "whateeever", "cooool", and "haaaapy", keep only

Will become:

> "whatever", (elong) "col", (olong) and "hapy", (along) keep only

If you change the search pattern to `(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}(\w*)` then the output can be `"whatever(elong)",` and not `"whatever", (elong)`

You can test here: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyrbm63d

Comment: Would that be `re.sub(r"(\S*?)(.)\2{2,}(\S*)", r"\1\2\3 (\2long)", the_string)`? Your code does not compile as is...

Comment: @dawg oh I kind of just tested the regexp and edited the code in the question. I'll edit it as you said

Comment: You still need a `.` in `re.sub` vs an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* is to combine a regex with string concatenations:

```
for w in ('whateeever', 'cooool','haaaapy'):
    print re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\1+', r'\1', w)+' (elong)'
```